# $(document).ready() equivalent for rails 3? Need highcharts to load correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a highcharts chart that is not loading.. and I want to do something like $(document).ready() to make that the js file containing the chart data is only ran after the partial etc have been passed into build full page.

How do I do this in rails?

Comment: So use `$(fn)` and move on. JavaScript -> *client side*. The partial (unless doing "AJAX") content is returned from the server at the same time as the rest of the page markup.

Comment: you seem to be mixing up what happens at server and what happens in browser ... question makes little sense

Comment: Like the other commenters, it seems you're getting confused between loading the partial on the server, and rendering JS at runtime. From what I can understand, I can make a basic answer, but you'll really need to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code?
});
```

If you put that in your application.js, it *should* work